# Ubuntu works well on LiveCD, but the GUI is extremely slow after fresh install

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, gui, nomodeset, xorg.conf

I'm having problems with a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I decided to install a new ssd on my laptop. It's a Lenovo G480 (i5 processor, 8GB of RAM and integrated Intel graphics). So I took out the old hdd and installed this new ssd. Then I went on to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

I booted with a LiveCD. There, the OS runs smooth (note: I had to boot with nomodeset or 'safe graphics mode', otherwise it won't boot). But after installing and rebooting to the new installation, the graphical interface is extremely slow.

I tried Ubuntu Mate and Xubuntu as well, just to see if it was a problem with the default GUI of Ubuntu.

On all these distros I have the same problem: on LiveCD the UI is smooth, but after installing, this fresh install GUI is very slow. For example, watching a youtube video is impossible.

On "Additional drivers" there are no proprietary graphic drivers available.

My previous OS was Ubuntu 18.04 iirc and I didn't have this problem.

[Here's a small video I recorded when I tried Xubuntu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE6jS.jpg)

Any ideas on what could be happening here? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

`lshw -c video`

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:e0000000-e03fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`swapon`

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-2 partition 976M   0B   -2
```

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
5ECN95WW(V9.00)
```

Comment: Can you update your question please, with the output of the commands `lshw -c video` and `swapon`

Comment: When you log in, after selecting your username, but before entering your password, click on the small icon in the lower right corner, and tell me what environment is selected, and what the choices are. I'm looking for wayland and/or xorg. Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I edited the questions with the output of those commands. About the environment options, it seems to me that I don't have the icon to change whatever environment I'm using (I'm assuming it's xorg). https://imgur.com/a/cvjPbhN